# Vue3 Web Component V-model

Tags: vue.js, web-component

i would to create a **web component with vue3** for manage inputs and forms.
**But i have problem with two data binding.**
I define the web component in my html page.

```
<vue-input-text id="prova_di_un_input_text" name="prova_di_un_input_text" value=''></vue-input-text>
```

and i hook the emit when i write

```
document.querySelector('#prova_di_un_input_text').addEventListener('update:value', function (e) {
        console.log("input cambiato", e, e.detail)

        let valore_da_aggiornare = e.detail[0].value
     
      });
```

but i don't understand how can update web component value after get new value.

thanks for every support

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement two-way data bindings in Vue (awesome, right?) yourself unless you need something specific. Just use `v-model` directive, here's the [doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#form-input-bindings)

Code example:

```
<vue-input-text v-model="myValue" id="prova_di_un_input_text" name="prova_di_un_input_text" />
```

```
const myValue = ref('')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer BUT this is not the solution. I can't use v-model with a web component. I can't use simple vue component. I used web component generated with vite started a vue file. In this situation i think i can't use v-model directive.

Comment: ah, I see. then you need to emit update event from your component

Answer (score 0):

> You should listen `update:modelValue` event not `update:value`.

vue component MyInput.ce.vue

```html
<script setup>

defineProps({
  modelValue: String,
})
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

function onInput(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value)
  emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value)
}

</script>

<template>
  <input :value="modelValue" @input="onInput" />
</template>
```

register web component in main.js

```js
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue'

import MyInput from './components/MyInput.ce.vue'

const MyInputEle = defineCustomElement(MyInput)

customElements.define('my-input', MyInputEle)
```

use `my-input` tag in html

```html
<my-input value="hello"></my-input>
<br />
<p class="my-p"></p>
<script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
<script>
    const myInput = document.querySelector('my-input')
    // listen update:modelValue
    myInput.addEventListener('update:modelValue', (event) => {
        const inputText = event.detail[0]
        document.querySelector('.my-p').innerText = inputText
    })
</script>
```